# how to show validation message on button click?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

could you please tell me how to show validation message on button click ? here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ugdbvg?file=src/app/app.component.html

I want to show `required` error message when user press `submit` button.

```
  <form novalidate [formGroup]="searchForm" class="calform">
      <section class="col-sm-6 bg-white  pl-20 pr-20">

      <div class="form-group col-sm-4 pl-0 error">
          <label class="field-title mb-5">name<span class="color-red fontWt">&nbsp;*</span></label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" formControlName="name">
          <p class="message" [hidden]="searchForm.get('name')">Required</p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-sm-4 pl-0 error">
          <label class="field-title mb-5">last name <span class="color-red fontWt">&nbsp;*</span></label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter last name" formControlName="lastName">
          <p class="message" [hidden]="searchForm.get('lastName')">Required</p>
        </div>
        <button (click)="submitHandler()">submit</button>
      </section>
    </form>
```

js

```
this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
          lastName: ['', Validators.required]

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to check:

```
<span class="error" *ngIf="!!searchForm.controls.name.errors.required && (!!searchForm.controls.name.dirty || !!searchForm.controls.name.touched)">
    Name is required.
</span> 
<span class="error" *ngIf="!!searchForm.controls.lastName.errors.required && (!!searchForm.controls.lastName.dirty || !!searchForm.controls.name.touched)">
    lastName is required.
</span>
```

in your ts file:

```
submitHandler() {
    if(this.searchForm.valid) {
        // Logic
    }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-utvw23

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *ngIf. Updated Stackblitz code . https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fzyrji

Comment: with ngif it is not possible

Comment: because ngif remove and add in dom ,I don't want to remove element . only hide and show

Comment: Ok Updated stackblitz with [hidden] attribute binding.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

Use `[hidden]` or `*ngIf`

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uk82ja)

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4 pl-0 error">
            <label class="field-title mb-5">name<span class="color-red fontWt">&nbsp;*</span></label> {{show}}
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" formControlName="name"> {{searchForm.get('name').invalid}}
            <p class="message" [hidden]="!(show && searchForm.get('name').invalid)">Required</p>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-sm-4 pl-0 error">
            <label class="field-title mb-5">last name <span class="color-red fontWt">&nbsp;*</span></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter last name" formControlName="lastName">
            <p class="message" [hidden]="!(show && searchForm.get('lastName').invalid)">Required</p>
        </div>

        <button (click)="show = true ; submitHandler();">submit</button>
    </section>
</form>
```